# Session timeout works different as i hope

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat, web-applications, jsf-2

I'm trying to configure a session-timeout to my application.

In web.xml i configured i minute, like this:

```
<session-config>
        <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
```

To have sure that everything is working i created i listener, see:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>br.com.sender.util.SessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

See my listener class:

```
package br.com.sender.util;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener;

public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        System.out.printf("Session ID %s created at %s%n", event.getSession().getId(), new Date());
    }

    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        System.out.printf("Session ID %s destroyed at %s%n", event.getSession().getId(), new Date());
    }
}
```

When i login in my application the session is created (in this same moment i store a UserMB with sessionScope), see:

```
Session ID 801040FAFEBC8D21C3C8E0DA56BF9B27 created at Tue Jun 10 18:44:33 BRT 2014
```

After some minutes without actions the session is destroyed:

```
Session ID 801040FAFEBC8D21C3C8E0DA56BF9B27 destroyed at Tue Jun 10 18:46:26 BRT 2014
```

When user click in some Menu or Button the session is created again, but i hope that UserMB (SessionScope) is distroyed and user must loggin again, but it's dont happens, user continue using application without re-loggin.

Comment: How are you checking that user is logged in? By session != null or by session.getAttrribute("someattribute")!=null? First one is wrong.

Comment: I have a UserMBLogged with SessionScope, when i need check if user is logged in i call this ManagedBean. I have a "Filter" that checks if user is logged in.

Comment: You call this managed bean to do what?

Comment: Well, i think that i found a solution: Using my "SessionListener" when session is destroyed i can call a method "setUserLogged(null)" and when filter is called the user don't exists and page will be redirect to login form. Right ?

Comment: You shouldn't have to do that. When the session is destroyed, everything is unbound from it, including your bean, and you can check that by making it a SessionBindingListener. You must have some faulty logic *inside* the bean. It would help if you would answer the questions you 're being asked.

Comment: I have a class called "AppContext" that store attributes. This class is not clear on session destroyed. So, think about that i SHOULD clear user logged attribute and everything works fine,

Comment: What does 'this class is not clear on session destroyed' mean? What does this class look like? What does your question mean?

Comment: Please add the `Filter` if you are storing references to session scoped object in there that isn't going to work.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `WebFilter` that checks for some attribute in your session scope and determine if user is logged in or not

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you have configured your `security` which you have not posted in the question.

If you don't verify your logged in user through `java ee web.xml` security settings or by checking through a `filter` than your pages are not secured and when the user will hit the next URL the `session` will be recreated .

If you are not using container security or java ee security then you can have some kind of filter that checks all your pages except login

```
@WebFilter("/*")
public class LoginFilter implements Filter {

    private ServletContext context;

    public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
        this.context = fConfig.getServletContext();
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, 
        FilterChain chain) throws   IOException, ServletException {

        String requestURL = ((HttpServletRequest)request).getRequestURL().toString(); 
        HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);

        if(session == null && !(requestURL.endsWith("login.xhtml"))){
            ((HttpServletResponse)response).sendRedirect("login.xhtml");
        }else{
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }  
    } 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You may have some servlet or filter written in your application which intercepts all requests and then forward it to right controller for request handling, so in that servlet/filter you have to check if session.getAttribute("someinfo") != null if its null then forward the request to the login page instead.